# Wrap directive content with ng-transclude not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following directive

```
<modal title="Login form" visible="true">
    Modal content
</modal>
```

And i have a `modal.template.html` file where I've included `<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>`:

```
<div class="modal">
   <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">Title</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
      <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>              
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to replace `ng-transclude` element for the directive content set on the main page. So I tried:

```
$app.directive('modal', function ($modal) {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'modal.template.html',
    controller: 'ModalController',
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: 'element',
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
  };
});
```

It displays my template on the main page but doesn't replace `ng-transclude` element for the directive content. I may understood wrong how `ng-transclude` works.

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/m9kpo38e/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-transclude` is an attribute directive **not an element directive.**

```
app.directive('modal', function () {
      return {
          template: '<h1>Content: <span ng-transclude></span> - End Content</h1>',
        controller: 'ModalController',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
      };
})
```

Comment: Thanks! It really solved my problem. But I was following this doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude. Is it wrong?

Comment: Seems like `ng-transclude` is made as an element directive in angular 1.4.  Your fiddle uses angular 1.2